# How to get row value when I check checkbox in datagrid with WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid

If user checked 'isACreer' and 'oldLibelle' (in same row) is empty, then I show a message box to inform user that is not authorized. How to do that in WPF ?

Here is my wpf code :

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:_Produits x:Key="_Produits"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="produitsViewSource" Source="{Binding Produits, Source={StaticResource _Produits}}"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DataGrid  x:Name="futureProductsDataGrid" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Margin="20" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code produit vinif"  Binding="{Binding codeVinif}" Width="105" IsReadOnly="true"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Libellé Actuel" Binding="{Binding oldLibelle}" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="true"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Libellé Futur"   Binding="{Binding newLibelle, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="SizeToCells"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="A créer ?" Binding="{Binding isACreer, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="80" >
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Checked" Handler="OnChecked"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Here is my C# code :

```
    private void GetProduits()
    {
        try
        {
            _produits = new _Produits();
            _produitsProduitsTableAdapter = new ProduitsTableAdapter();
            _produitsProduitsTableAdapter.Connection = new OleDbConnection(_connectionString);
            _produitsProduitsTableAdapter.Fill(_produits.Produits);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _loggerComavi.Error("Erreur lors du chargement de la table Produits");
            _loggerComavi.Error(ex.Source);
            _loggerComavi.Error(ex.Message);
            _loggerComavi.Error(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }


    private void OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _loggerComavi.Info("OnChecked");
       //TODO MessageBox.show()
    }
```

Here is a screenshot :
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)e.OriginalSource;
    DataGridRow dataGridRow = VisualTreeHelpers.FindAncestor<DataGridRow>(checkBox);

    var produit = dataGridRow.DataContext;

    if (checkBox.IsChecked && String.IsNullOrEmpty(produit.oldLibelle)
    {
        // Show message box here...
    }


    e.Handled = true;
}
```

I do not know how the products look like that are bound to the grid which come from your table adapter.
But you should be able to find your `oldLibelle` property somewhere in the `produit` object mentioned above.

Please note that this solution uses the custom `VisualTreeHelpers` class (written by Rachel Lim). It can be found [here](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/navigating-wpfs-visual-tree/).
I provides the `FindAcenstor` method used above.

`VisualTreeHelpers` uses the .NET class [VisualTreeHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) internally.

Comment: Thanks Martin, but FindAncestor is not a method of VisualTreeHelpers (https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)...

Comment: The .NET class is called "VisualTreeHelper" without the 's' at the end. "VisualTreeHelpers" (with the 's') is a custom class written by Rachel Lim. You can find it if you follow the 'here' link and my answer. "VisualTreeHelpers"  uses "VisualTreeHelper" internally.

Comment: my apologize ! Thank you. I will give you my feed back later ;-)

Comment: It works fine ! Thanks you @Martin :-) !! I just missed how to uncheck checkbox in this case ...

Answer (score -1):

this will popup a message bix and you can take action on OK press.

```
MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Please enter the empty field to proceed?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Asterisk);
            if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {

            }
```

please try. thankyou.

Comment: Yes thank you. But my issue is to filter when I show popup, i mean only when 'oldLibelle' is empty AND checkbox is checked. Any idea ?

Comment: yes check with e. and it will show the selected item

Answer (score -2):

Here is full code:

```
private void OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)e.OriginalSource;
        DataGridRow dataGridRow = VisualTreeHelpers.FindAncestor<DataGridRow>(checkBox);
        DataRowView produit = (DataRowView)dataGridRow.Item;

        if (produit[3].Equals(""))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
                "Vous ne pouvez pas ajouter cette appellation car elle n'était pas créée l'année dernière. Veuillez la créer manuellement.", "Erreur",
                MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);

        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```